# Rollup summary using Batch Apex on Parent object

Tags: apex, batch, custom

I've got two objects connected via a lookup relationship. What I am trying to do is update some fields on the parent object based on the child object(Custom Roll-up summary)

My current implementation:

1. On a child object, as soon as some fields are updated, a flag field is immediately updated on the parent via a flow. That flag determines whether to recalculate the roll-up summary on the parent.(Since it's fired every time a child is updated, I assume it's not a good solution. That is, if a parent has multiple children, the parent will be updated to the same flag whenever any of the children is updated.)
2. Every day, one batch apex fetches all the child records whose parent flag is set as true.
3. Afterwards, it calculates all the child records' values and updates the parent record. Here, the parent is updated based on all the child's records. Since, in between, any child record can be deleted, taking all the child is the safer option. See the diagram below for a basic idea
   .
   [image]
   So, I would like to know if there is a better optimized solution using the combination of Batch Apex or automation tools. Thanks.

Comment: if the batch apex runs daily; you could use a scheduled flow instead if the # of records isn't to large as to exceed flow limits

Comment: You could also look at updating a flag on the child records themselves rather than the parent. That would prevent any issues with row-locking where the parent was being updated at the same time in separate transactions.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich the parent record could be locked anyway depending on the deletion behaviour for the child's Lookup field.

Comment: Is the batch using aggregate query to calculate the rollup value? What are the data volumes? Could you do this incrementally in the child trigger (handling insert/undelete, update and delete events) entirely synchronously?

Comment: That's a great point, I should have thought of that! I was meaning the behaviour when the field is updated rather than where one child is updated and another is deleted at the same time, but that's a good point.

Comment: Hi @cropredy, Numbers of records can be large. So, I guess it's safer to use Batch Apex.

Comment: Hi @philw, no I'm not using any aggregate query. I'm calculating inside a for loop, since there are some multiplications, summations etc.

Comment: There are lots of other functionalities on the child trigger, data volume can be up to 50/100k per day.

Comment: How many children will you need to query per parent? We have a "child" with a lot of processing in the trigger too, and have implemented incremental management of some pseudo-rollups successfully. There are some hoops to be handled, but it is robust and functional. Of course, your "rollups" may be too complex for this approach. We have a technique for generically flagging and clearing records for processing using 2 datetime fields and a checkbox formula; the two datetime are when processing was identified as needed and when processing was last done. The checkbox looks for processing > done.

Comment: The checkbox formula field (which also looks for processing set with done being null) allows selection of the required records via SOQL (you cannot test one field value against another in SOQL WHERE clauses, and this approach gets round that restriction).

Comment: In terms of your multiplication and summation, again, could formula fields on the child help here so you have trivial summation to the parent level?